# DRY a view function

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have the same function `full_name` in three different views (`user_view.ex`, `group_view.ex` and `connection_view.ex`). How can I refactor it that it's DRY? I want the `full_name` function just in one place in the project.

```elixir
defmodule MyApp.GroupView do
  use MyApp.Web, :view
  alias MyApp.User

  def full_name(%User{first_name: first_name,
                      last_name: last_name,
                      honorific_prefix: honorific_prefix,
                      honorific_suffix: honorific_suffix}) do
    [honorific_prefix, first_name, last_name, honorific_suffix]
    |> Enum.reject(&(&1 == ""))
    |> Enum.join(" ")
  end  
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since templates are just functions, you can define common functions in some helper module and import it into every `View` where you need it.

```
defmodule MyApp.UserHelpers do
  def full_name(...)
    # ...
  end
end

defmodule MyApp.UserView do
  use MyApp.Web, :view
  import MyApp.UserHelpers

  # ...
end
```

Comment: The `import MyApp.UserHelpers` can be put into `web/web.ex` so you don't have to repeat the import.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways around it. The simplest way is to just put that function in a separate module and just import it anywhere you need it but I imagine that would be a mess so you should design your application first and come up with a proper way to go around it. You should not be scared of creating your own folders and structure elements in your app.

As I mentioned in the other answer, you could just create a separate structure element, like decorators ( not sure if the name is appropriate) so then it would be something like that:

```
defmodule MyApp.UserDecorator do

  def full_name(%MyApp.User{first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name} = user) do
    first_name <> " " <> last_name
  end

end
```

Then, you can use it anywhere in your app.